# flask-sqlAlchemy perform function before inserting/updating

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app using SQLAlchemy.

We have two models (that are relevant).

1. Parent
2. Child

Each parent can have multiple children referred to by a foreign key. A child must have a Parent

I would like to have an instance attribute for each parent which is equal to the name of the youngest child.

At the moment I have this working with a function `youngest_child()` which loops through all children of the parent and finds the youngest and returns the name of that. Clearly, that's inefficient to do it each time.

Instead, whenever a new child is created or a child has its parent updated I would like to set the `youngest_child` attribute for the parent.

Is there a way to do this with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: If the childrens age/day of birth are in the table, select parent_id as the first param. Sort on age and only select first one.

Comment: @Wimanicesir that's effectively what I'm doing although I should definitely sort first. But I wonder if there's a way so that I don't have to perform that lookup everytime and instead store the youngest child's name in the table

Comment: Once your store the youngest child, the next time you only have to check when inserting new childs if these are younger then the youngest child. If you mean with younger, a newer entry. Just always replace it when inserting a new child.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using a hybrid property:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Parent(Base):
    ...
    children = relationship("Child", order_by="Child.age")

    @hybrid_property
    def youngest_child(self):
        """
        children are already sorted by their age in the relationship.
        This offers an advantage in performance when children are frequently
        accessed through their sorted property.
        """
        return self.children[0] if self.children

# -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -

# Another approach – without pre-defined ordering
class Parent(Base):
    ...
    # Don't order the children
    children_no_order = relationship("Child")

    @hybrid_property
    def youngest_child_no_order(self):
        """
        children are not automatically sorted by their age.
        Do so with a subquery hybrid.
        """
        query = Child.query\
            .filter(Child.parent_id == self.id)
            .order_by(Child.age)\
            .first()
        
        # I chose to write this query in this format bc it helps with debugging
        # You could just as easily return the query without saving its state...
        return query
```

For more advanced implementation, see [Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid).